# java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, wiremock

Getting error

`Could not write JSON: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String (through reference chain: com.mediamath.octane.royaloak.model.Bank["ids"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])`

```
@Builder
@Value
public class Bank {
    private List<String> ids;
}
```

```
public void addId(List<String> ids) {
HttpEntity<Bank> request = new HttpEntity<>(Bank.builder().ids(ids).build(), headers);
ResponseEntity<Bank> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(testUrl, request, Bank.class);
}
```

This is from wiremock

```
    public void mockResponse(int statusCode) {
        JsonObject body = factory.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("ids", factory.createArrayBuilder()
                        .add("testId")
                        .add("testId2")
                        .add("testId3")
                        .build())
                .build();
        stubFor(post(urlPathMatching("/testUrl"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(statusCode)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBody(body.toString())));
    }
```

I am getting the exception shown above and I believe it has to do with jacksons marshelling. Am I creating and deserializing the response wrong?

Comment: What exact content is produced by `body.toString()`?